# Can Central Limit Theorem say anything about Probability Density Function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

For a sequence $\left( X_1, X_2, \dots \right)$ of independent and identically distributed random variables with zero expectation and unit deviation, CLT implies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \leq x \right) = \Phi\left( x \right),\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R},
$$
where $\Phi$ is a CDF of standard normal distribution.
To say something about the PDF of the limit of the sequence, I would like to use a derivative and exchange it with the limit like
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \Phi\left( x \right) =
\underbrace{\frac{d}{dx} \lim_{n\to\infty}}
  P\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \leq x \right) = 
\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d}{dx}}
  P\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \leq x \right),
\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
However, there are a few issues:

1. The probability density function may not exist for any finite $n$: for example, if $X_1$ has a binomial distribution with non-zero probabilities of failure and success and more than one trial. Or is it okay to use Dirac delta function?
2. Even if all the densities exist, I need a uniform sequence convergence to exchange a limit sign with a derivative.

Which conditions must be satisfied to infer the PDF from CLT?
Does it become more straightforward if the density of $X_1$ exists and is differentiable?

Comment: The derivative of $\Phi(x)$ is the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$, that is (by definition) the way $\Phi(x)$ is defined.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "local limit theorem". A classical reference on the subject is the book "Limit distributions for sums of independent random variables" by Gnedenko and Kolmogorov.

Comment: @Michh, thank you very much! It looks like it contains the theorems I need. I'm lucky that I can read it in the original language.